# Spring boot profile based WAR using maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, deployment, war

I need to create WAR file based on specific environment properties file.

So I have created 2 properties files,

- application.DEV.properties
- application.PROD.properties

Now when I run the project using eclipse embedded tomcat, I pass on the `-Dspring.profiles.active=DEV` as VM argument. Then when I hit my endpoint, I can see the DEV related messages returned. Same is the case when I pass PROD as parameter.

Now, what I want to do is I want to create a WAR file with maven command and pass the parameter in such a way that my specific properties file gets loaded. So I have referred google as well as stackoverflow and found various options like below,

1. mvn clean install -Drun.profiles=DEV
2. mvn clean install -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=DEV"
3. mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active="DEV"
4. mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=DEV

I tried all above. When I hit the command, the WAR gets generated. but it doesn't get deployed on tomcat, because it cant read the properties file and gives error. It seems like the profile specific properties file does not get loaded in the WAR.

I want to know what is the alternative to `-Dspring.profiles.active=DEV` when I want to generate a WAR file using maven?

How to generate WAR to correctly include proper profile specific properties file?

I am using spring boot 1.5.14.RELEASE.

Comment: It seems like a resource directory problem. Can you edit your POM with full path resources folder. <resource><directory>to/your/resource</directory></resource>

Comment: Hello. I think you confused Spring profiles and Maven profiles. If you want to build and/or deploy a package base on a profile you should use Maven profiles instead of Spring profiles.

Comment: all of the steps (1.-4.) were good, but only applying to "mvn clean install" (run). I remember that it was "bad practice" to build (different) artifacts depending on the environment (prod, dev, int,..)., but you can do it (e.g. with "maven profiles")..To activate spring profiles, you have to set the according properties on the runtime (start tomcat (or whatever) with `-Dspring.profiles.active=...`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented on this answer by Mickael, you can get help from the maven documentation on how to use profiles : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

The usual way to choose a profile with maven is

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

Where prod is the name of your profile. If you want to build with the dev profile, it would be

```
mvn -Pdev package
```

Such profiles are defined in your file `pom.xml` under `project>profiles>profile`. And at that place, you can specify packaging options.

Here is such a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <!-- log configuration -->
        <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        <!-- default Spring profiles -->
        <spring.profiles.active>dev${profile.no-liquibase}</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Is "mvn clean install -Pdev" alternative to "mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev" ?

Comment: I'm not used to the syntax you're using and no (next comment says it is not). I've completed my answer with the profile definition.

Comment: `mvn clean install -Pdev` **IS NOT** an alternative to `mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: @Mickael what should be the way to go then to create that WAR using maven to pick specific profile?

Comment: mvn -Pprod package

Comment: You should use this answer. Here's the full documentation : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Marking this as an answer as it was what I would have done. However, I went for another approach of using @PropertySource with "file" location.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass `spring.profiles.active` to the runtime, not to the "build runtime". The only spring profiles, which are desirable at build time, would be for testing purposes.

In case of "war on Tomcat", you can set `spring.profiles.active`:

1. (Globally) Create a file in `<tomcat_home>/bin/` named `setnev.sh` (respectively `.bat`, when you are on a Windows machine) with:

   ```
   export JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=PROFILE_OF_THIS_TOMCAT"
   ```

   respectively:

   ```
   set JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=PROFILE_OF_THIS_TOMCAT"
   ```
2. (Globally) Add a line to `<tomcat_home>/conf/catalina.properties`:

   ```
   spring.profiles.active=PROFILE_OF_THIS_TOMCAT
   ```
3. (At Container level) Add a file named `context.xml` at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` (, you could also put it into `/<webapp_root>/META-INF/`, but then you'd have to distinguish at build time) with the following content:

   ```
   <Context>
    <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="PROFILE_OF_THIS_TOMCAT" /> 
   </Context>
   ```

Comment: Just a note, I couldn't get the application to start until I also added the type to the Environment. What worked for me was `<Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="PROFILE_OF_THIS_TOMCAT" type="java.lang.String" />`. After adding the type, the application was able to start in the correct environment.